# Select K edges with minimum weight in linear graph

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, graph-theory

We are given a linear graph with `N` vertices. The task is to select `K` edges with no overlapping vertices than have minimum weight.

As an example, in the graph below, where `N = 5` and `K = 2`,

[image]

the answer is

[image]

Because it has the minimum possible possible weight (2 + 2 = 4). Note thath we couldn't select edge with weight 1 because in that case, the next possible edge to select would be 6 which leads to a greater weight sum (1 + 6 = 7).

**My solution so far:**
I have solved the problem in `O(NK)` time and `O(N)` memory using dynamic programming. I store an array `DP_k` of size `N`, where `DP_k[n]` is minimum weight of `k` edges selected from the first `n` edges. Then I build the array `DP_k+1` by iterating from 0 to `N` and the formula `DP_k+1[n] = min(weight[n] + DP_k[n - 2], DP_k+1[n - 1])`. I do this for `k = 1` to `k = K` and return `DP_K[N]` as the answer which leads to `O(NK)` time.

But I need to reduce the time complexity. I would really appreciate any hints on how I can do this.

Comment: Any and all algorithms will need to at least look at every edge weight - so O(N-1).  Your algorithm is as fast as any possible algorithm.

Comment: @ravenspoint my algorithm time complexity is **O(NK)**. The memory is O(N). I wish to reduce the time. Do you think it's possible?

Comment: No, for the reason I stated.

Comment: @ravenspoint There is a lot of room between `O(N)` and `O(NK)`.  You have not shown that there isn't a solution somewhere in that range less than `O(NK)`.

Comment: K is a small integer.  It can be ignored.

Comment: @ravenspoint The problem does NOT say that `k` is a small integer.

Comment: You will have to ask the OP about that - I cannot help you any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an `O(k log(n))` answer [here](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/59818) from Codeforces.

> (I) For every 1 ≤ i ≤ n, insert i with cost ai into a priority_queue whose top element has the minimum cost. And keep a linked-list 1, 2, 3, ..., n.
>
> (II) Repeat the following steps k times:
>
> (II.a) Pick the top element x from the priority_queue.
>
> (II.b) Add the cost of x into the answer.
>
> (II.c) Change the cost of x into costprex + costnxtx - costx, where prex and nxtx are the previous and next element of x in the linked-list.
>
> (II.d) Delete prex and nxtx from the linked-list and the priority_queue.
>
> (II.e) Insert x with new cost into the priority_queue.

Answer (score 2):

Two ideas:

1. There’s a [kernelization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernelization) that consists of using a linear-time selection algorithm to remove all but the lightest 3(K−1) + 1 edges. The idea is that, if a solution contains a removed edge, then there exists a lighter edge not in the solution that we can replace it with, since K−1 edges can make a total of only 3(K−1) edges ineligible to be added. This reduces the running time to O(N + K²).
2. One way to deal with troublesome constraints is to introduce a [Lagrange multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). The idea is to reformulate the problem as

> min<sub>independent set I</sub> max<sub>λ</sub> (∑<sub>e∈I</sub> w(e) + λ (|I| − K)),

since if |I| ≠ K, then the max is ∞. By strong duality, we can equivalently solve

> max<sub>λ</sub> min<sub>independent set I</sub> (∑<sub>e∈I</sub> w(e) + λ (|I| − K)).

Looking at the interior minimization, since λ is fixed, it’s equivalent to finding a maximum weight independent set. Since the graph is a path, there’s a classic linear-time dynamic program. Then we can find λ with binary search (if I is too large, then the true λ is larger; if I is too small, then the true λ is smaller). Assuming integer weights summing to W, the running time should be something like O(N + K log W).

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to implement the solution,
the simplified task is:

Finding the minimum sum of `k` values from array of size `n`, so there are no following indexes.

my solution:

```py
def min_sum_k_exclude_adjacent(arr, k):
    n = len(arr)
    if 2 * k > n:
        return -1 # no solution

    i = 2 * k - 1

    # include will always consist i
    include = [2*a + 1 for a in range(k)] # k indexes of arr
    include = sort_by_weights(include, arr)

    include_sum = sum([arr[index] for index in include])

    # exclude will never consist i
    exclude = [2*a for a in range(k)] # k indexes of arr
    exclude = sort_by_weights(exclude, arr)

    exclude_sum = sum([arr[index] for index in exclude])

    i = i + 1
    while (i < n):
        if include_sum < exclude_sum:
            exclude = set(range(0, n, 2)) - set(include)
            exclude_sum = include_sum

        j = find_location(include, arr, val=arr[i])
        
        # replace the minimum value
        include_sum -= arr[include[0]]
        include.pop(0)
        
        # with arr[i]
        include_sum += arr[i]
        include.insert(j, i)

        i += 1
    
    if include_sum < exclude_sum:
        return include, include_sum
    else:
        return exclude, exclude_sum
```

helper functions:

```py
def sort_by_weights(index_list, weights):
    return sorted(index_list, key=lambda x: weights[x])

def find_location(include, arr, val):
    # Binary search to find index
    low = 0
    high = len(include) - 1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2

        if arr[include[mid]] == val:
            return mid

        elif arr[include[mid]] > val:
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            high = mid - 1

    return high
```

the code should solve the problem with a time complexity of `O(n*log(k))` and space complexity of `O(k)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your nice answer and suggesting the simplified form. But I can't understand some parts of the code. I tested `min_sum_k_exclude_adjacent([2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1], 3)` and the return value was `([0, 2, 4], 6)` whereas the minimum possible selection is `{2, 2, 1}` which sum up to 5.